# Converting from scala.collection.immutable.List to a java.util.List in java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I’m currently working within a java runtime google cloud dataflow. The scala sdk I'm using shows the property I'm working with as an immutable list: https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow-scala-analytics-sdk/blob/master/src/main/scala/com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow.analytics.scalasdk/Event.scala#L91

final List<SelfDescribingData> contexts

Does anyone have any pointers on how to properly cast / convert this to a Java list? Most of the examples I have found are doing this in the Scala runtime vs the Java runtime.

I had thought the JavaConverters package would help me here, however these methods don't seem to be expecting an immutable scala list.

Where e in the example below is an instance of the Event in the linked sdk.

```
List<SelfDescribingData<Json>> list = JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter(e.contexts()).asScala().toList();
for (SelfDescribingData<Json> t : list) {
    LOG.info(t.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter`:

> Adds an asScala method that implicitly converts a Java List to a Scala mutable Buffer

To convert a `scala.collection.immutable.List`, which is a subtype of `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` and `scala.collection.Seq` to a `java.util.List` you would call `JavaConverters.asJava`:

```
java.util.List<SelfDescribingData<Json>> list = JavaConverters.asJava(e.contexts().data())
```

The code I've posted is after the Scala 2.13 collection rewrite.  For older versions of Scala, the equivalent function is `JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList`